# Generating letters using 'for' loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have to generate 80 random letters of the English alphabet (capital letters) and display them in a row of 10 letters per row using a 'for' loop. I get an error because the limit is 26. What do I change in the code?

```
alfabet = 'A' : 'Z'; 
for i = 1 : 80
temp = alfabet(i);  
swop = floor(rand *26  + 1); 
alfabet(i) = alfabet(swop); 
alfabet(swop) = temp;
end 
for i = 1 : 10 : 80
disp(alfabet(i : i + 9))
end
```

Comment: The tag [tag:matlab-guide] is for MATLAB GUI development, which you don't seem to be doing. Likewise, I don't see that you're building a standalone executable file for your script, so [tag:matlab-compiler] is also incorrect. Please read the descriptions more carefully before adding tags to your post.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. My question was Matlab related and I thought that these tags were appropriate. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it could be an one-liner:

```
disp((char('A'+randi(26,8,10)-1)));
```

Surely you can split it with a usage of "for":

```
alfabet=char('A'+randi(26,1,80)-1);
for i = 1 : 10 : 80
    disp(alfabet(i : i + 9))
end
```

If for whatever reason you have to use a  "for" for the random letters:

```
for i=1:80
    alphabet(i)=char('A'+randi(26)-1);
end
```

Frankly speaking, I don't find this part attractive.